# is_front_page() doesnt work in ajax theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i am trying to add the below code in an ajax wordpress theme in order to show a div only in front page

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()): ?>
 <!-- Do the things here... -->
<?php else: ?>
 <!-- Else part goes here...  -->
<?php endif;  ?>
```

unfortonatly it doesnt work when accessing from menu to other pages for example :

HOME-->SECOND PAGE--> THIRD PAGE

it works only if i access direct to an other page : for example :

www.example.com/secondpage

do you know any solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this article](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-homepage-conditional/) on how to properly use `is_front_page` and `is_home` functions.

Basically you should use this code:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ){
    // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page()){
    //Static homepage
} elseif ( is_home()){
    //Blog page
} else {
    //everything else
}
```